# Legends dissapeared when exporting Highcharts SVG code to TCPDF

Tags: php, svg, highcharts, tcpdf

I'm trying to export SVG data to TCPDF and it's working fine using following code.

```
$pdfobject->ImageSVG('@'.$datasvg);
$pdfobject->Output($pdffilename, "F");
$pdfobject->Close();
```

SVG data is coming from Highcharts.

The chart is appearing in pdf just fine but the problem is that the legends text is not appearing.

If I view this SVG into browser, I can see the legends text but TCPDF is somehow skipping legends text.

Anything here I'm missing ? Or is there anything I need to change in SVG data ?

Comment: It may be caused by setting `useHTML` flag for legend, [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/label-and-string-formatting) you can read more about HTML in Highcharts.

Comment: @PawełFus no, I didn't enable it. I found out TCPDF is crashing on some <tspan> tag. Amazingly, it stucks under legends only, while main chart title is also in <tspan> but that works.

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge is very limited for TCPDF, maybe someone else could answer you, sorry.